# Вычесть 1 день из даты в Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть исходный DF :

```
Data
01.03.1962
01.04.1962
01.05.1962
```

Нужно получить на день раньше, то есть:

```
Data
28.02.1962
31.03.1962
30.04.1962
```

Comment: смотрите библиотеку https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для действий с датой используй [**timedelta** объект](https://python-scripts.com/datetime-time-python):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)
```

В твоем случае:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start_date = datetime.datetime(1962, 3, 1) # год, месяц, число
result_date = start_Date - timedelta(days=1)
```

[Похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441147/how-to-subtract-a-day-from-a-date)

Comment: ссылки на источники кода следует приводить, если используете. Похожий код и другие решения https://stackoverflow.com/q/441147/4279

Comment: @jfs Спасибо за информацию. Надалее буду надавать ссылку с похожим решением. Я так понял,, эту ссылку нада давать в коментарие к самому вопросу?

Comment: если  вы чужой код из другого StackOverflow ответа используете, то прямо в своём ответе на него и ссылайтесь.

Answer (score 4):

Pandas умеет делать это сам.

Исходный DF:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
        Data
0 1962-03-01
1 1962-04-01
2 1962-05-01
```

Решение:

```
In [8]: df.Data - pd.offsets.Day(1)
Out[8]:
0   1962-02-28
1   1962-03-31
2   1962-04-30
Name: Data, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

или так:

```
In [9]: df.Data - pd.to_timedelta('1 day')
Out[9]:
0   1962-02-28
1   1962-03-31
2   1962-04-30
Name: Data, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```